# Facebook OAuth login workflow

Tags: facebook, oauth-2.0, omniauth

my facebook app Flixstreet is used for client side authentication on https://www.flixstreet.in. Off late a problem has occurred. If a user is logged out of both Facebook and https://www.flixstreet.in and tries to login from my website(using the login button which basically fires the oAuth dialog with the auth URi, client callback URI and perms) the app falls into an infinite loop and never logs the user in. My app runs on ROR and I use omniauth for authentication. However strangely, when a user is logged into Facebook but not my site the auto login flow( with the same piece of code as the login button) works perfectly fine. Could you please help me in debugging this issues as it is crucial to our web application.

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem. How did you fix this ?